Migration to .Net 3.1 Controller calls are redirected to Login
Recently migrated .Net 2.2 website to .Net 3.1 (On my way to .Net6 or 8)
It's a website built with razor pages and a handful of controllers.  Another application calls these controllers to read in various items.
After migrating to .Net 3.1, the website works as normal, but none of the controller actions are working.
We use [Authorize(Policy = "ApiKeyPolicy")] on our controller class for our authorization.
And pass that key as usual.  However, the calls redirect us to the /Account/Login page.
Here are some relevant code snippets:
Starup.cs
 services
     .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
     .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
     {
         options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
         options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
     });

 services.AddDbContext<BlahContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), x => x.MigrationsAssembly("Blah.Blah.Blah")).UseLazyLoadingProxies());
 services.AddDbContext<BlahBlahContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BlahConnection")));

 services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, ApiKeyRequirementHandler>();
 services.AddAuthorization(authConfig =>
 {
     authConfig.AddPolicy("ApiKeyPolicy",
         policyBuilder => policyBuilder
             .AddRequirements(new APIKeyRequirement()));
 });
 services.AddAuthentication(options => { options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; });

And... (The commented part is what we had for 2.2)
  //services
  //    .AddMvc()
  //    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
  //    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
  //        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
  //        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
  //    });
  services.AddRazorPages();
  services.AddControllers()
      .AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
          options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
          options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
       });

and...
 app.UseRouting();
 app.UseSession();
 app.UseCookiePolicy();
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();

 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
     endpoints.MapRazorPages();  
     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
         name: "default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
     endpoints.MapControllers();  
 });

 //app.UseMvc(routes =>
 //{
 //    routes.MapRoute(
 //        name: "default",
 //        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
 //});

My controller (Simplified)
  [Authorize(Policy = "ApiKeyPolicy")]
  public class StorefrontController : Controller
  {
...
  ///Example method
  [HttpGet]
  public virtual async Task<IActionResult> PendingOrders()
  ...

I've searched and tried to rearrange my startup.cs file, but I don't see that I'm missing anything or that the order is wrong.
In 2.1 I would get an error if the Key was incorrect, in 3.1 it just routes me to the login page, so I suspect I'm not getting very far with my 3.1 call.
Update: [AllowAnonymous] on the controller does allow access to the methods.  So we're hitting the right spot, it just doesn't respect my API key.
Update (API Key Check):
    private void RequirementCheck(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, APIKeyRequirement requirement)
{
    if (context.Resource is AuthorizationFilterContext authorizationFilterContext)
    {
        var apiKey = authorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[API_KEY_HEADER_NAME].FirstOrDefault();
        if (apiKey != null && requirement.APIKey == apiKey)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
        else
        {
            var authFilterContext = context.Resource as AuthorizationFilterContext;
            authFilterContext.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }
    }
} 

The first if fails, as contextResource is NOT that type.  I'm sure this is a change in 3.1 that I"m missing.
Anyways, we're re-writing our functions in a new controller in .NET 8, so this is more of an informational exercise, would still appreciate sorting it out.

You can check whether APIKeyRequirement and APIKeyHandler are correctly implemented. For details, please refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-8.0.
And check whether the API key can be read and verified in APIKeyHandler.

@YuningDuan All of this code is working in .NET 2.2.  It's the migration to 3.1 that has affected it.  Do we know of any APIKeyHandler changes that were changed with 3.1?

Would you be able to post your ApiKeyRequirementHandler code?

not sure why you're adding Razor configs there.  Is that something you used before the move?  (as is the controller's are not razor controllers so you should probably remove all the razor setup stuff.)  You might also look into changes with JSON...  I believe around that time they switched versions of Newtonsoft, or to System.text.json: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-package-references-for-removed-assemblies
